# Encode PKCS7 in Google App Engine (python, passbook)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, encryption, pkcs#7, passbook

This question pertains to Passbook which is under NDA for the next few days, but this is a generic PKCS7 question.

I have a .p12 file that is exported from my keychain.  I am able to separate this into 2 pems using the following commands

```
openssl pkcs12 -in "mycert.p12" -clcerts -nokeys -out certificate.pem
openssl pkcs12 -in "mycert.p12" -nocerts -out key.pem
```

The next step is to use this key and certificate to create a signed PKCS7 file.  This is easy to do with openssl:

```
openssl smime -binary -sign \
    -signer certificate.pem -inkey key.pem \
    -in <datafile> -out signature \
    -outform DER
```

The question is, what is the best way to do this in Google App Engine, assuming I have the certificate and key?  Unfortunately I'm a little new to cryptography, but I've been googling around and found PyCrypto and keyczar.  Is there an accepted way to do this on App Engine, or will I need to write something?  Any recommendations on which package to start with?
I know that openssl is not available on AppEngine, but PyCrypto is if you use python 2.7, right?  And I've seen posts of people getting keyczar to work with it.  I have not been able to find a simple way of generating PKCS7-encoded data given the key and certificate, though.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: I've managed to cobble together a workaround by querying a secure remote server explicitly to do the signing part, but obviously this is less than ideal.  I'd still love to hear if anyone solves this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using M2Crypto taken from https://github.com/devartis/passbook

```
def passwordCallback(*args, **kwds):
    return password

smime = SMIME.SMIME()
smime.load_key('key.pem', 'certificate.pem', callback=passwordCallback)        
pk7 = smime.sign(SMIME.BIO.MemoryBuffer(manifest), flags=SMIME.PKCS7_DETACHED | SMIME.PKCS7_BINARY)                
pem = SMIME.BIO.MemoryBuffer()
pk7.write(pem)
# convert pem to der
der = ''.join(l.strip() for l in pem.read().split('-----')[2].splitlines()).decode('base64')        

open('signature', 'w').write(der)
```

Comment: Unfortunately M2Crypto is not accessible in Google App Engine, I think because it is using c under the hood.  GAE currently only supports PyCrypto 2.6

Comment: This is a generally useful answer although not for GAE. Your github link is 404.